# Load example GraphSON file in Gremlin with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin

I'm trying to load the example *Graph of the Gods* file that is distributed with Titan with the *loadGraphSON* function. I have executed the following steps and are working with Titan 0.5.4 with Hadoop 2.

1. Downloaded and unpacked a fresh Titan 0.5.4 with Hadoop 2.
2. Started Titan, Rexster, Cassandra, ElasticSearch with the command `bin/titan.sh -c cassandra-es start`
3. Run Gremlin with: `bin/gremlin.sh`
4. Open a new TitanFactory instance with the required settings: `g = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')`
5. Then I tried to load the *Graph of the Gods* from the *examples*-directory with `g.loadGraphSON("examples/graph-of-the-gods")`

I do not get an error, but trying to show all vertices with *g.V* returns nothing. Am I executing the rights steps here, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this question was answered on the Aurelius Graphs Mailing List:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/FiCvX891r6g/BkmWj3xc3ikJ

Basically:

> 1) the filename should be examples/graph-of-the-gods.json
>
> 2) you can also use GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(g) which will also create indexes and type definitions

I'd say the second point above would be the preferred manner in which to load Graph of the Gods.

Comment: The wrong filename was a typo of me here on StackOverflow, I have used the correct filename in Titan. Unfortunately, the correct filename also does not load the Graph of the Gods data into the graph. I'm aware that I can use the GraphOfTheGodsFactory, but I would also like to use my own custom JSON-files and load them into graphs. Of course I can't use the GraphOfTheGodsFactory then.

Comment: Does `g.V` return nothing in the console after you `loadGraphSON` or when querying through Rexster?

Comment: Exactly, it returns no nodes, only a warning: WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes

Comment: I think that your problem is that the `graph-of-the-gods.json` file is meant for consumption by titan-hadoop - it's adjacency list format.  `loadGraphSON` is meant to read GraphSON represented as: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tinkerpop/rexster/master/rexster-server/data/graph-example-1/tinkergraph.json

Comment: The other GraphSON format (the one in your link) does indeed work as expected and loads the data into the graph. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not setting up a Titan Hadoop job, you could try using the Blueprints GraphSON reader to load graph data.  See https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphSON-Reader-and-Writer-Library

In a Gremlin shell it looks a bit like this:

```
inStream = new FileInputStream("../examples/graph-of-the-gods.json")
GraphSONReader.inputGraph(g, inStream)
```